# Get selected dates on Bootstrap Datepicker as string?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker having `multidate: true` event. And I am getting the selected date one by one, using:

`.on('changeDate', function(e){
    console.log(e.format('mm-dd-yyyy'));
})`

Is there any ways to get all the selected dates altogether as string?

**Note: The string should contain the dates which I have selected, and should not contain which I have unselected.**

Here is my code so far:

```
$('.check-in').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   startDate: "1d",
   format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
   weekStart: 1,
   orientation: "bottom auto",
   todayHighlight: true,
   multidate: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
   console.log(e.format('mm-dd-yyyy'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value as a string you can use this

```
>> var value = $("#dateID input").val();
```

I hope this can help you. :)

Comment: I am using an Inline datepicker, so no input field is there and thus console.log() is being used there.

Answer (score 0):

So did it myself. Thank you all for help.

```
$('.check-in').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   startDate: "1d",
   format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
   weekStart: 1,
   orientation: "bottom auto",
   todayHighlight: true,
   multidate: true,
   sideBySide: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
       var dates_arr = [];
       for(i=0; i<e.dates.length; i++){
          dates_arr.push((String(e.dates[i].getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')) + '-' + String(e.dates[i].getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + e.dates[i].getFullYear());
       }

       console.log(dates_arr.join());
});
```